# Lemma 2.3 of do carmo's Riemannian geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Obviously, theorem 2.2 state the uniqueness of trajectory .but in the proof of lemma, why the uniqueness of trajectory means the uniqueness of $G$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice that the value of $G$ at a given point $p$ is the derivative at $p$ of an integral curve of $G$ passing through $p$. This determines the vector field $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the trajectory *defines* G. The condition placed on G is that it is defined by such a trajectory. Thus, there can only exist one such object: the one defined by the only trajectory that fulfills the required conditions.